# Calculate the initial velocity needed for a ball to hit a target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

How would I get the initial velocity needed for a bullet to hit a target when the following are all constants

```
time to target
gravity
initial position of the ball and the target
radius of the ball
```

I am doing out a few examples in Unity 3D using c# for the code.  I am not asking for the code, I just would like to know what steps to take to do this (physics wise).

Comment: The time it takes for your bullet to hit the ground is constant, because its acceleration in y is constant (aka gravity). Thus it needs to have enough velocity to hit the target in x in less time than it takes to hit the ground.

Comment: Do you know the position of the target? Look into [SphereCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html)

Comment: You may be better off posting a question like this in http://physics.stackexchange.com/ if the question is code-independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question can be solved using [Kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics). You need to know a few things about Physics, but it is all very simple.

1. When the bullet is fired the only force acting on the bullet is gravity.
2. Acceleration on the x-axis will be 0.
3. Acceleration on the y-axis will be gravity.

Let us examine what we know:

- time
- gravity
- distance_to_target

To calculate you will need these equations:

```
VelocityFinal_x = VelocityInitial_x

FinalDistance_x - InitialDistance_x = VelocityInitial_x * time

VelocityFinal_y = VelocityInitial_y + gravity * time
```

---

Just rearrange the second equation to find `VelocityInitial_x`

Notice that we didn't need to use z-axis. Don't touch the z-axis unless the wind is moving the bullet in mid-flight.

Make sure you do these calculations once at the instant the bullet is fired, don't do it every frame of the game.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, i really appreciate it and you breaking it down to be so simple to understand, just one question, i understand the x and z axises, but cant work out the y, could you give me a bit info on that please.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about y-axis?

Comment: Ill try explain this easily I use 
float velocX = (target.transform.position.x - ball.transform.position.x)/desiredTimeOfFlight;
for the X axis and similar for the z 
But when I try add gravity to it to achieve the Y velocity I just get crazy numbers. 
So basically I dont understand how to add the gravity for the y axis

Comment: You only need to use the x-axis and y-axis. Y velocity will be `V_y = Vinitial_y + gravity × time`. Don't touch z unless the wind is moving the bullet in mid flight. Also only apply the velocity once, not in every frame.

Comment: It's an interesting answer but just to take it a step further, how would you factor in the drag ?

Answer (score 0):

A nice [article on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile) regarding trajectory of projectile with detailed explanation of two-dimensional case (3D case may be easily reduced to 2D if you define a plane included start point of projectile, target point and vector of gravity).

[image]

To hit a target at range x and altitude y when fired from (0,0) and with initial speed v the required angles of launch *theta* are:

[image]